# Import error in Django url.py

Tags: python, django, import, django-views, pycharm

I just started a django project but i cant import a function from views.py.
I have done some projects with very similar settings with this framework but without any problems.
I'm using virtualenv(and it is activated), windows10, pycharm.

```
#urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from WebShop.main_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^index/', views.index),
]

#views.py
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hi</h1>")

 #cmd 

  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\b021l\Desktop\practice\django\WebShopProject\WebShop\WebShop\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from WebShop.main_app import views
ImportError: No module named 'WebShop.main_app'
```

*Edit

I also added the virtualenv to the projects interpreter in pycharm.

btw my filestructure is basic:

```
-WebShopProject
 -env
 -WebShop
  -WebShop
    -__init__.py
    -settings.py
    -urls.py .....
  -main_app
    -__init__.py
    -views.py ...
```

**update

still nothing.. I have reinstalled python, re started the project, fresh virtualenv, configured virtualenv as default interpreter in pycharm, still nothing.. Tried to put urls.py in my 'main_app' folder and included it in 'WebShop.urls.py' and guess what i cant import from the same folder..

*fixed
I dont know what happened it just started to work, maybe it is buggy for windows :/ although thanks for the answers.

Comment: Have you included the app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` file? You might also want to try `from WebShop import views` or `from main_app import views`, but this depends on your file structure.

Comment: Yes, it is in the installed apps. None of these those two imports are working.. I can only type WebShop.main_app

Comment: Have you added `WebShop.main_app,` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` or just `main_app,` ?

Comment: I have added just main_app

Comment: That should be right, but try with `WebShop.main_app` as well.

Comment: It's not working with WebShop.main_app in installed_apps either. I have done a few projects but never had this problem :/

Comment: I have encountered a similar problem today @Zozo, Could you please tell me how you solved it?

Answer (score 3):

from your file structure it seems like you need to do
`from main_app import views`

Comment: from main_app import views try this hope this will work

Comment: well i guess there should be __init__.py file in your app directory

Comment: Django generates it when i create a app